# Is there a way to abbreviate a custom class type declaration?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to create an abbreviation, or custom class name, for:

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<int,myClass>>
```

I can create

```
class DD
{
   public Dictionary<string,Dictionary<int,myClass>> wDD;
}
```

but then when I use it I have to say:

```
DD.wDD wrkVar = new DD.wDD();
```

instead of

```
DD wrkVar = new DD();
```

Is there a way to get `DD` to refer directly to

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<int,myClass>>
```

?

**EDIT - showing solution based on responses below**

I arrived at this, which works:

```
using DBDDict = 
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,    
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, DDRow>>;

public class CustomClassTest
{
    public static void Test4()
    {
        DDRow wrkRow = new DDRow();
        wrkRow.ColumnName = "ABC";
        Dictionary<int, DDRow> wrkRowD = new Dictionary<int, DDRow>();
        wrkRowD.Add(1, wrkRow);
        DBDDict wrkDD = new DBDDict();
        wrkDD.Add("key", wrkRowD);

    }
}
```

AND, so does this, which is easier to work with (note the "using" is commented out).

```
//using DBDDict = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, DDRow>>;

    public class DD : Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, DDRow>> {}

    public class CustomClassTest
    {

        public static void Test4()
        {
            DDRow wrkRow = new DDRow();
            wrkRow.ColumnName = "ABC";
            Dictionary<int, DDRow> wrkRowD = new Dictionary<int, DDRow>();
            wrkRowD.Add(1, wrkRow);
            DD wrkDD = new DD();
            wrkDD.Add("key", wrkRowD);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What data you store in this type?

Comment: Thnx to all; will test soon and post back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherit from the type you are 'aliasing'

```
public class DD : Dictionary<string,Dictionary<int,myClass>>  { }
```

Comment: These two cases are not equivalent. Inheritance is not the same as composition...

Comment: I think what he wants is "is a" not "has a". He's shown a composition example and stated that it doesn't give him what he wants. So I think inheritance is what he's after.

Comment: @LeonBambrick: grazie! that's a real gift

Answer (score 6):

You can create an alias to use in your source file as follows:

```
using FancyDic = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,myClass>>;
```

But this will have to be repeated in every code file where you want to use the 'FancyDic' alias.

Once this is declared though, you can create new objects as follows:

```
 var newDic = new FancyDic();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use an alias via the `using` statement, called a [using alias directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx), outside of your namespace, where you normally place using declarations in each file:

```
using System; // etc.
using DD = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, MyNameSpace.MyClass>>;
```

Then to instatiate,

```
public void SomeVoid()
{
    var dd = new DD();
}
```

Variable dd will now be exactly what you set up the `using` alias with:
[image]

- **Pros:** No need to create a separate class just for code design purposes.
- **Cons:** Need to repeat `using alias directive` in each file where you want to use this.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to "shorten" that class declaration and BTW, this...

```
Dictionary<string,<Dictionary<int,myClass>>
```

will not compile, you need to change it to...

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<int,myClass>>
```

Furthermore, this...

```
DD.wDD wrkVar = new DD.wDD();
```

will not compile either since the wDD public field can not be invoked with a constructor syntax. This,

```
DD wrkVar = new DD();
wrkVar.wDD;
```

is the correct way to access that public field. You can "shorten" the class instantiation but not the class declaration by inheriting from that dictionary...

```
public class DD : Dictionary<string,Dictionary<int,myClass>>
{
}

DD d = new DD();
d.Add("key", new Dictionary<int,myClass>());
```